# FTP Implementation, List the files from server without using Apache Common Library

Tags: ftp

For my project, I am trying to implement File Transfer Protocol. I wrote a code for uploading and downloading without using Apache Commons library.

Now I want to include the option for "listing the files in the server", but I don't want to use any third party API's. Is there a way to list the files in the server without using third party API?

Answer (score 0):

If you have implemented download using FTP protocol without any 3rd party library, then adding a directory listing is trivial.

Just replace the `RETR` command with `LIST` (or `NLIST` or `MLSD`).